# rhdfs is not getting connected

Tags: windows, r, hadoop, cygwin, rhadoop

I have set the **HADOOP_CMD**(hadoop path) variable but it is not taking the path,saying as not found

```
library("rhdfs")
hdfs.init()
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CMD="C:/cygwin64/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop") 
Error in system(command, intern = TRUE) : 
'C:/cygwin64/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop' not found
```

I have defind HADOOP_CMD in system env variable also as well as in cygwin by

```
export HADOOP_CMD="C:/cygwin64/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop"
```

where am i wrong,any help in this direction,thanks.

Comment: i am having same problem how did you solved it? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`HADOOP_HOME` & `HADOOP_CMD` should be set in R session, before calling `hdfs.init()`

Also remember following **checkpoint** before staring RHadoop

- R-Hadoop dependencies

  - **rmr2** - `RCpp, RJSONIO, digest, functional, stringr, plyr`
  - **rhdfs** - `rJava`
- Export env variables in R Session before running `init()`

  `# requied

     Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME="/home/trendwise/apache/hadoop-1.0.4");
     Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CMD="/home/trendwise/apache/hadoop-1.0.4/bin/hadoop");
     Sys.setenv(HADOOP_STREAMING='/home/trendwise/apache/hadoop-1.0.4/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.4.jar')`

  `#optional

     Sys.setenv(HADOOP_BIN="/home/trendwise/apache/hadoop-1.0.4/bin");
     Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CONF_DIR="/home/trendwise/apache/hadoop-1.0.4/conf");
     Sys.setenv(HIVE_HOME="/home/trendwise/apache/hive-0.10.0");
     Sys.setenv(HBASE_HOME="/home/trendwise/apache/hbase-0.94.3");`

  `# Library Path
  Sys.setenv(LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/lib:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib64:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib64:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/jre/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/jre/lib/amd64/server");`

  `# Loading library

     library(rmr2)

     library(rhdfs)`

  `# initializing

     hdfs.init()`